# Rails environment config and client-specific deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, configuration, capistrano

Rails is developed with support of multiple environments. By default, there are three of them: test, development and production. In reality, you usually end up having more environments, such as staging, beta, etc.

Capistrano deploy scripts are usually in parallel with environment configs.
So let's say you have `config/environments/production.rb`, then you most likely also have `config/deploy/production.rb`.

Now imagine that you have different clients. They have different deploy scripts, `RAILS_ENV` for each of them is unique, so that they'll have different Redis namespaces, ES indexes, caches etc. While in essence all these clients have production environment config, convention forces me to create exactly the same environment config for each of them.

Is there any way to use production environment config for other `RAILS_ENV`s?

Note that duplication in `config/environments/` is minimal. Each of the client_env environment configs is only applying production config, it's just the matter of single line.

Edit: Clients are deployed on different machines and must be fully isolated.

Comment: Sounds to me like it would be simpler to have one production environment and have an environment variable (or several) controlling the rest, but it is not clear from the above what your constraints are (eg are these apps all hosted on the same machine, what is the level of isolation between clients etc.)

Comment: If I add another env variable, isolation will break. RAILS_ENV is used to isolate things (to create redis namespaces, cache keys, ES indices, etc), often impicitly. I guess I can try to override it, but it's rather scary. It's quite easy to miss something.

Comment: You are doing it right. As you said, it is only a single line of code that you need for each separate environment file. That is not bad at all, and you have the safety of following Rails conventions.